# Is there a way to book a two-way flight where the return flight is more than a year after departure?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines

I'd like to fly from Israel to Australia and to have the possibility of returning more than a year after the outgoing flight. So far the flight conditions I have checked only allow up to a year difference between the outgoing and the return flight, and even if I change the date of the return flight, I can only do this to a date which is up to a year after the outgoing flight.

Is there a way to do this without paying for two one-way flights?

The reason is that one-way flights tend to be around the same price as two-way flights and I will end up paying much more if I book two one-way flights.

Comment: [I think it's not possible](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60080/is-there-any-airline-alliance-that-offers-round-the-world-tickets-for-more-than).

Comment: Have you actually looked at prices? Maybe it's just me, but I find more and more cheap one-ways recently.

Comment: It does not seem like a duplicate to me. I am asking about returning after **more** than a year abroad. I am also open here to the possibility of rebooking the return flight at some point.

Comment: @fiftyeight flag it for moderator intervention